# jquery collapse all does not work when combined with HAML format

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

My Exapand All button works fine (collapses and expands) in the following jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/HqXMN/6/

But the Expand all/Collapse all feature does not work  when used in a HAML format.. I am not able to determine where the problem exists.

Here is my code in HAML.

```
%a{ href:"#", class: "expandcollapse"}
  %i.icon-white.icon-plus-sign
  Expand All
#programs-accordion.accordion
  - @patient_summary.programs.each_with_index do |program, index|
    .accordion-group
      .accordion-heading
        .accordion-toggle.group-accordion-toggle
          %a{ href: "#collapse-#{index}", data: { parent: '#programs-accordion', toggle: 'collapse' }}
            %i.icon-plus
          %a= program.name
         .accordion-body{id: "collapse-#{index}", class: (@office.to_i == office.id) ? "" : "collapse" }
           .accordion-inner 
            - office.positions.each_with_index do |position, index|
              #measures-accordion.accordion
                .accordion-group
                  .accordion-heading
                    .row-fluid
                      .span2{class: "offices-#{position.status}"}= position.status
                      .span1= position.results.first.value
                      .span2= position.results.first.value_date_time.blank? ? '' : Date.parse(position.results.first.value_date_time)
                      .span5= position.name
```

NOTE: I have updated the jsfiddle link

Comment: `class: (@office.to_i == office.id) ? "" : "collapse"` This line may be of some issue. Beyond that it looks pretty solid. **Can you put in the html it generates?**



One last thing, I would definitely recommend looking into doing partials for these loops.  It would definitely clean up the code a bit and give you some more reusable chunks.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is the html. http://pastebin.com/Q0jxpUVE

Comment: in the HAML you provided, `.accordion-body` appears to be indented 9 spaces.

Comment: that was some copy paste issue. My indentation is correct in my ide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. So there doesn't appear to be anything obviously wrong with your code.  I was able to take the generated content and put it into jsFiddle and it worked fine.

I can't post the jsFiddle because I need to accompany it with code, but I don't have any relevant code to go along with it. Sorry.

Check to make sure there isn't anything a miss in your javascript, but beyond that there doesn't seem to be any issue.

I would still recommend that you look into rendering partials, if only from a cleanliness of code standpoint.  Hope that helps a bit.